# Confluent Kafka schema not found error from producer when auto register is off

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have a schema registry, kafka, zookeeper with a producer running locally. Problem is that when I manually register the schema and turn off auto register on the producer, I get the following exception when I try to produce records to the topic. What's confusing is that I've verified that the schema is available after manual register using POST, so not found doesn't really make sense. Any help on this is highly appreciated. BTW enabiling auto register on the producer makes all this work, but I really need to turn it off and manually register my schemas.

```
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:230)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:256)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:323)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.lookUpSubjectVersion(RestService.java:311)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getIdFromRegistry(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:191)
at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.getId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:323)
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:73)
at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53)
at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:62)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:903)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:865)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:752)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code generating that error?

Comment: What version of the serializer are you using? The error should say the subject name / schema ID trying to be used (I added that feature)

Comment: @OneCricketeer I found the issue and you can find my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: if schema is changed we have to register is once with producerProps.put("auto.register.schemas", true);, for subsequent request we can set it to false.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to troubleshoot and find out why I was getting that exception. So after de-compiling the code for the Kafka producer and a bunch of other classes that it uses (from Confluent), I saw that the producer was POST-ing to this endpoint `/subjects/myTopic-value` of the schema registry (when `producer.send(...)` called), where it could send the schema in the request as a JSON payload and check if it has a schema matching the one sent over. Important thing to realize here is, the string that basically defines the schema which is stored in the schema registry needs to match exactly with the schema string received by that endpoint.

Now this is where my troubles began, I was using HttpPost with StringEntity. It turned out that my `'` inside the schema string were turned in to `?` (which is difficult to see in a large AVRO schema file) and as such there was no match when querying the schema registry. The reason is the schema registry would receive a schema string with `'` turned to `?` and then later would get queried on with the schema string with `'`, which is a mismatch and would result in 40403 error with the exception as seen above.

So as for the fix, make sure to mention UTF-8 as the charset (UTF-8 encoding) when constructing StringEntity class.

Comment: You used Apache HTTPClient for the Schema Regsitry? You should really use `CachedSchemaRegistryClient` provided by Confluent

Comment: Now that I searched it, I’m gonna give that a go and clean this up. I couldn’t find a mention of this when I was looking for ways to submit schema to the schema registry on Confluent docs, all I saw was curl commands to POST to the schema registry. Well you live and learn right ;)

Comment: I am using CachedSchemaRegistryClient to register subject-key and subject-value. The interesting thing is that I can register the key, value and write to the kafka topic in batch mode. However, when I transition to streaming mode, the job fails with - org.spark_project.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Schema not found; error code: 40403
Any clue what could be wrong?